# Replicating cURL post in Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle

I was using cURL for posting data to an API but have decided to switch to Guzzle.  Using cURL I would do this

```
$data = 
"<Lead>
  <Name>$newProject->projectName</Name>
  <Description>$newProject->projectName</Description>
  <EstimatedValue>$newProject->projectValue</EstimatedValue>
</Lead>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.someurl.com/lead.api/add?apiKey=12345&accountKey=12345");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is what I am currently attempting with Guzzle.

```
$data = "<Lead>
            <Name>$campaign->campaignName</Name>
            <Description>$campaign->campaignName</Description>
            <EstimatedValue>$campaign->campaignValue</EstimatedValue>
          </Lead>";

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$req = $client->request('POST', 'https://somurl', [
    'body' => $data,
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($data),
    ]
]);
$res = $client->send($req);
$output = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

The first problem I am facing is that it is stating that arguement 3 for request needs to be an array, and I am passing it a string.  Thats fine, but then how can I send my xml block?  Additionally, I think I may have set the headers incorrectly?

I have gone through the documentation and see that parameter 3 needs to be an array, but I do not see how to post an XML string.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `$client->request('POST', 'http://whatever', ['body' => $data]);`

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Mark as answer and I will accept.  Do you know how I can set the headers?#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an array using the 'body' param:

```
$client->request('POST', 'http://whatever', ['body' => $data]);
```

Read more at: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=post#post-form-requests

To set headers, you can do something like:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://whatever', [
    'body' => $data,
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($data),
    ]
]);
$output = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Read more at: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers

Comment: I was trying something similar but I get Type error: Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface

Comment: @kate_hudson You don't need to to `$client->send` . `$client->request` will itself make the request for you. See: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1779189/17643835/13f487e8-6193-11e6-9e25-01f30c691873.png